# Creating named session array from mysql fetch array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, session

I have a database with a table called translations.  It has several columns, but I am trying to create a session array to house a variale:translations named array.

I've tried the below code, but I must be missing something... my end goal is to populate much of the static verbiage of a website using `$_SESSION['TRANSLATIONS']['Userboards']` for example to populate the names of otherwise static content into any language supported based on the database.

```
$querylang = "SELECT variable,translation FROM translations left outer join languages on languages.abbrev = translations.fkabbrev WHERE languages.abbrev = 'EN'";
        $sqllang = mysql_query($querylang);
            while($reslang = mysql_fetch_array($sqllang)){
            $_SESSION['TRANSLATIONS'][$reslang['variable']] = $reslang['translation'];
            };
```

Comment: Hi! First off, did you remember to start the session? Secondly, are you getting any errors? If you are, please include them in your question.

Comment: Yes I started the session.  It's an existing page, and all I've done is added the above just prior to returning 'success' to the main login page.  I just checked the log and do see:syntax error, unexpected T_ELSE in

Comment: Well, I can't see any else code, so you'll have to update your question with the code containing the error.

Comment: Figured it out, the above actually worked, but I have an extra ' { ' that didn't belong.

Answer (score 0):

The above code is actually correct.  The reason it didn't work was a separate issue.  Thanks to @Epodax for reminding me to check the errorlog!